# is it possible to do the equivalent of SQL nested requests in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, equivalent

it is possible to do in Pandas dataframe the equivalent of this SQL code

```
delete * from tableA where id in (select id from tableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact structure of your DataFrames, but something like this should do it:

```
# Setup dummy data:
import pandas as pd
tableA = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[1, 2, 3]}) 
tableB = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[3, 4, 5]})

# Solution:
tableA = tableA[~tableA["id"].isin(tableB["id"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an equivalent. You can try this:

```
df2.drop(df2.loc[df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])].index)
```

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4], 'value': [2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4, 5,6,7], 'col': [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
print(df2.drop(df2.loc[df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])].index))
```

output:

```
   id  col
4   5    6
5   6    7
6   7    8
```

I just took random example dataframe. This example is dropping values from df2 (which you can say TableA) using df1 (or TableB)